# is it possible to make reference to an index entry

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing

my document looks like this

```
    \section{Foo bar}
    \label{sec:foo}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit\index{blahblah}
    \section{laborum}
    As seen in section \ref{sec:foo}, ...
```

And I want be more precise as the section "foo bar" may be long and I just want to refere to the index entry `blahbla`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I don't exactly what you want to do. Do you need compatibility with `hyperref`? Give a more detailed explanation of what do you want

Comment: Use the `hyperref` package if you want to link directly to the referent; this package also gives you access to the command `\phantomsection`.  Or use `\pageref` (which is compatible with `hyperref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to refer to a page number within the Section Foo Bar?  In that case, you can simply create a label wherever you want it to be, and use \pageref:

```
\section{Foo Bar}
\label{foo:bar}
... [lots of text going on for pages and pages]
\label{relevant:page}
... [lots of text going on for pages and pages]
\section{Foo Baz}
As seen on page \pageref{relevant:page} in Section \ref{foo:bar},...
```

I don't know of any way to do it other than creating a new label at the appropriate place in the text.  LaTeX has no way of knowing which location within a section you want to refer to unless you tell it.

You could also create subsections, paragraphs, or some similar sectioning command and reference that, if it would be more suitable to your purpose.

As others have noted, though, your question is ambiguous.  Do you want to refer to just a part of the section, or to an entry in an index, or to the text which creates an entry in your index, or something else?  It's quite hard to tell.

Comment: Did this answer your question?  Do you need more help?